# CSS Firefox issue: Maintain relative size of side-by-side divs of differing widths inside a Flexbox when resizing

Tags: javascript, css, image-resizing

I'm creating an image gallery of cards of different dimensions and orientations using Flexboxes (closed covers next to open interiors). Recent vintages of Chrome and Safari resize/shrink side-by-side divs of different widths images just fine, respecting/keeping the relative sizes of the two divs as the browser window shrinks. Firefox hits a limit and starts to shrink the wider div/img more aggressively, resulting in 2 divs of 2 different heights and destroying the original layout relationship.

**Is there a CSS solution to this problem WITHOUT resorting to multiple divs with different percentages** for every unique div size difference or using @media calls. Looking for an elegant solution (a single div wrapper) that scales/shrinks both side-by-side divs while maintaining relative height or width no matter what size card is placed inside the div.

I've tried 2 percentage divs side-by-side, and it works fine and as expected. But that solution will necessitate creating a bunch of individual CSS divs just to satisfy Firefox.

In the jpg examples below, the cover image is the same file for both the folding and flat card. The only difference is the bottom flat card has css round corners. Clearly the issue is with the two different widths of the folding card example.

I'll use a .js solution if that's the only remedy. But my current .js skills are at the "cut and paste and break" level. (My css skill may be only slightly better!)

Chrome/Safari vs Firefox scaling image here:
[Firefox scaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTSfb.jpg) | [Chrome/Safari Scaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Znqjq.jpg)

```css
.designFold  {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0 auto 1% auto;  }


.spacer {
    flex:0 1 auto;
    -webkit-flex:0 1 auto;
    margin: 0 2%;  }
    
    
.b-sqr  {
    flex:0 1 auto;
    -webkit-flex:0 1 auto;
    -moz-flex:0 1 auto; 
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    border: 1px Solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 7px #f2f2f2;    }


.b-rnd  {
    flex:0 1 auto;
    -webkit-flex:0 1 auto;
    -moz-flex:0 1 auto; 
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    border: 1px Solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-shadow: 8px 8px 7px #f2f2f2;    }
```

```html
<div class="designFold">
        <div class="spacer"><img class="b-sqr" src="cards/A1-C.jpg"></div>
        <div class="spacer"><img class="b-sqr" src="cards/A1-O.jpg"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide accesible images for the snippet ?

Comment: Image links are provided above the code above, where it says "Chrome/Safari vs Firefox scaling image here: Firefox scaling | Chrome/Safari Scaling

Answer (score 0):

try using https://modernizr.com/ - what it does is normalizing css3 and html5 differences with browsers. Many devs use this.